# Conditional time formula in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, datetime, time

I have a column formatted by "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" (AKA: datetime for mysql).
However, some of the times have not been set (ie. 00:00:00).

I'm guessing I can't sort by the time-portion alone of the datetime column in excel, so I think I need a formula to determine if the cell has time 00:00:00.

Can anyone help shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the results, so this formula will simply return TRUE/FALSE depending on if the time portion is 00:00:00

```
=MOD(A1,1)=0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure I understand why MOD works, but it does. Maybe I need to read up a bit more on that function.

Comment: MOD works because how excel records time is in days from a starting date.  Fractions of dates are stored as fractions of a number.  using mod 1 returns the fractional part of the time, so if the time is not present it would return 0=0 so true, otherwise some decimal = 0 which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Assume starting values in A:

- in B fill values matching that of A shows this if you format the
  value as number (instead of date)
- Now use a formula to subtract off the full days.
- Now use a new column D and set D = C but apply D format as time.
- Now sort on column D, the time alone.

you can shortcut much of this to just the formula to get to the fractional day and format it as time, but I wanted to show all the steps individually to add clarity.  This could be done using the below example by: `=A2-TRUNC(A2,0)` in column b then sort.

[image]

Instead of using trunc, `=mod(a2,1)` should also work.